# Information Retrieval :URL hits in a time frame

Tags: algorithm, information-retrieval

Algorithm Challenge :

Problem statement : 
How would you design a logging system for something like Google , you should be able to query for the number of times a URL was opened within two time frames.

i/p : start_time , end_time , URL1
o/p : number of times URL1 was opened between start and end time.

Some specs :
Database is not an optimal solution
A URL might have been opened multiple times for given time stamp.
A URL might have been opened a large number of times within two time stamps.
start_time and end_time can be a month apart.
time could be granular to a second.

Answer (score 0):

One solution :

Hash of a hash

Key Value 
URL Hash----> T1  CumFrequency

Eg :

Amazon Hash-->  T        CumFreq
              11 00 am       3  ( opened 3 times at 11:00 am )
              11 15 am       4  ( opened 1 time  at 11:15 am  , cumfreq is 3+1=4)
              11 30 am       11 ( opened 4 times at 11:30 am , cumfreq is 3+4+4=11) 
i/p : 11 : 10 am , 11 : 37 am , Amazon

the o.p can be obtained by subtracting , last timestamp less then 11:10 which 11:00 am , and last active time stamp less than 11:37 am which is 11:30 am. Hence the result is 
11-3 = 8 ....

Can we do better ?