# Design a logging system for something like Google, to get the frequency of a URL being clicked in a specified timeframe

Tags: algorithm

Hi This is a question from one of the interviews from [CareerCup](http://www.careercup.com/).

Problem statement : How would you design a logging system for something like Google , you should be able to query for the number of times a URL was opened within two time frames.

i/p : start_time , end_time , URL1 
o/p : number of times URL1 was opened between start and end time.

Some specs : Database is not an optimal solution A URL might have been opened multiple times for given time stamp. A URL might have been opened a large number of times within two time stamps. start_time and end_time can be a month apart. time could be granular to a second.

---

My approach:

Logging System: Build a hash table of key as url and value as an arraylist of times when the url was clicked.
Query time: when a timeframe is given, apply a modified binary search and get the positions between that timeframe and then count the number of times the url was opened between that timeframe

Can someone please comment on my approach or suggest a better approach. Thanks.

P.S. I have had a look at this ([Information Retrieval :URL hits in a time frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824189/information-retrieval-url-hits-in-a-time-frame?rq=1)) but I did not find it very helpful so asking again.

Comment: Google have a Website\URL statistics API, integrate with it and query by your time-frame

Answer (score 0):

I would have approached the problem as below-

## Storage

I would use a HashMap having 
 Key    --->  URL
 Value  --->  ArrayList of Date

Every time a URL is clicked, I will add/update entry in the hashmap above.

## Retrieval

For the given timeframes t1 & t2 and the URL, I will get arraylist corresponding to the URL and find the positions of t1 & t2. The just have a counter to increment until t2 is reached.

Comment: Given low time T1 and high time T2 do binary search of ArrayList to find (the first item >= T1) = arrayList[t1] and (the last item <= T2) = arrayList[t2].  t2 - t1 + 1 == click count.  No incrementing should be required.

Comment: @munna I have mentioned the same approach in my question. But I'm curious to know if that is a good approach. Looking at the size of the web, using a hashmap does not sound like a good idea to me.